# Getting two Python scripts to work together

Tags: python, class, function, colors, tkinter

I'm making a simple drawing pad program with pygame and I'm making it so you can define your own color. I'm using a tk window to do this but I cant figure out how to get them to work together. Please help, I've been trying to get this to work for hours

Here is my Tk code:

```
from Tkinter import *
r = 0
g = 0
b = 0

class Custom():
    def get_color(self):        
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.configure(background='black')
        self.root.wm_title("Custom")

        label1 = Label(self.root, text='Red Value:',bg="black", fg="white")
        label1.grid(row=2, column=0,columnspan=2)
        self.enter1 = Entry(self.root, bg='white')
        self.enter1.grid(row=3, column=0,columnspan=2)


        label2 = Label(self.root, text='Green Value:',bg="black", fg="white")
        label2.grid(row=4, column=0,columnspan=2)
        self.enter2 = Entry(self.root, bg='white')
        self.enter2.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)

        label3 = Label(self.root, text='Blue Value:',bg="black", fg="white")
        label3.grid(row=6, column=0,columnspan=2)
        self.enter3 = Entry(self.root, bg='white')
        self.enter3.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2)

        btn1 = Button(self.root, text='OK', command=self.close, bg="black",activebackground="green", fg="white")
        btn1.grid(row=14, column=0, columnspan=2)
        label7 = Label(self.root, bg="black", fg = "white")
        label7.grid(row=15, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.enter1.focus()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def close(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def return_color(self):
        r = int(self.enter1.get())
        g = int(self.enter2.get())
        b = int(self.enter3.get())
        return (r,g,b)
```

It works fine, but I can't get it to return the three values to my pygame program.

Here is the pygame snippet:

```
if key[pygame.K_c]:
    import CustomColor
    c = CustomColor.Custom()
    c.get_color()
    self.color = c.return_color()
```

Current Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Drawpad.py", line 75, in <module>
    draw.main()
  File "C:/Python27/Drawpad.py", line 69, in main
    self.update(screen)
  File "C:/Python27/Drawpad.py", line 45, in update
    self.color = c.return_color()
  File "C:/Python27\CustomColor.py", line 41, in return_color
    r = int(self.enter1.get())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2391, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
 TclError: invalid command name ".19783112"
```

I've been tweaking it, but just getting different error messages. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you post your error messages, it's more likely someone will help you out.

Comment: ive had a ton becuase ive changed my code so much

Comment: When you run it now, it only generates one error message. Post that. And if you have another version that generates another error message, post that message too.

Comment: alright ill have to change my code back ive already tweaked it from this

Comment: Why are you trying to use pygame and tkinter at the same time? You realize that while `root.mainloop` is running, the entire `pygame` UI is blocked—no redrawing windows, handling events, etc., right?

Comment: ohh so should i just make a box that pops up in my pygame window that takes input?

Comment: Yes, that's the easy solution—use pygame to do the color window (whether it's a popup or embedded in the main window). You _can_ make two graphics frameworks with their own event loops work together, but it's not easy. But anyway, this is a side issue; it's probably not your actual problem.

Comment: so if im make another file that generates a inputbox and then blits it to the pygame screen that would be way easier

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, it _might_ be your issue. You're trying to access a bunch of `Entry` objects after the `root` has been destroyed. (If we could see your actual code and errors, that would make it a lot easier to guess…) If so, you can work around this problem just by stashing the values in int member variables in your `close` method, and then access those variables in `return_color`.

Comment: Another side note: That `r = 0`, etc., at the top is misleading. You're creating three global variables that you don't use anywhere, but you do use local variables of the same name in various places. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Also, it looks like you already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877242/trouble-with-classes-and-functions), got an answer, accepted it, decided it didn't work, and asked a new question. If this really is a followup rather than the same question again, at least provide a link. If it _is_ the same question, don't ask dups of your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're trying to access `Entry` objects after they've been destroyed.

You can fix that very simply:

```
def close(self):
    self.r = int(self.enter1.get())
    self.g = int(self.enter2.get())
    self.b = int(self.enter3.get())
    self.root.destroy()

def return_color(self):
    return (self.r,self.g,self.b)
```

The reason this is happening is that, when you call `get_color`, that calls `self.root.mainloop`, which means it can't possibly return until the Tk event loop has exited, which means calling your `close` method, which means `self.root.destroy` is guaranteed to have happened before you can call `return_color`.

Calling a function that blocks on the Tk event loop is going to have other problems as well. Your pygame event loop is stuck waiting for Tk. So, your pygame window can't redraw itself, minimize, or respond to any other events.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i think like you siad it would probably be easier to do it using pygame Thanks So much!!